# Is it necessary to use the definite article before the adjective "proper" and a nount?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Couuld you tell me if it is necessary  to use the definite article before the adjective *proper* and a nount? For example:

> There are really good Englih dictionaries, but they sometime fail to give (**the**) proper explanation of when to use one word and not the other.
>
> You had better put on (**the**) proper clothes for the occasion.

In these two examples I am not talking about some specific explanations or clothes. In my experience, it seems, I've always seen *the* used with *proper*, so I wonder if it's correct and natural to omit it in my examples.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example *explanation* is countable, so it requires an article; but either article is possible. If you use *the* it implicitly says that there is only one possible explanation; if you use *a* it does not make this implication - it does not imply anything about how many explanations there are.

In the second one, *clothes* is plural, so it cannot take *a*; but it can either take *the* (definite) or nothing (indefinite). The distinction is the same as in the first case: *the proper clothes for the occasion* implies that there is only one proper way of dressing (not in the sense of "that particular jacket, shirt, trousers", but in the sense of "that kind of assemblage"), whereas *proper clothes for the occasion* allows the possibility that there is more than one way of dressing that is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I'm sorry, but I made a mistake. I meant "explanations", not "explanation". For example: ...give (the) proper explanations of when..."